# How would I print out the first instance of a paragraph bundle in a node template?

Tags: theming, 8, paragraphs

I have a node type `article` with a paragraph field `field_sections` with the available bundles `section_image` and `section_text`.  In my `node.html.twig` file I'd like to render out the first instance of any `section_image` bundles that may have been added. Any ideas on how to achieve this? Not sure if twig logic is correct way to go about this or if I should have a function in my .theme file that does the logic and returns a variable to do this that I could use in the twig file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TWIG**

In twig you can check for the paragraph bundle in the items loop of a field template and only print the first item found:

*field--node--field-paragraph--content-type.html.twig*

```
  <div{{ attributes }}>
    {% for item in items if item.content['#paragraph'].bundle == 'paragraph_type' %}
      {% if loop.index == 1 %}
        <div{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

And then print this field in the node template:

```
{{ content.field_paragraph }}
```

**UI**

For a UI solution you need a field formatter like [Paragraphs summary formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_summary), which in the moment only exists in a sandbox version, see https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_summary/issues/2803859#comment-11804075

Comment: Thank you! Also posted an alternative below using node_preprocess.

Comment: Yes, you can do this in preprocess, but if you use php, then the field formatter is probably a better place for this. You can copy the sandbox project and adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @4k4!

Very interesting.. Another solution I discovered here using the Paragraph's issue queue:

https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2925077

Code dump of final solution:

https://gist.github.com/krisrobinson/2e45bd817d562c3c6bc0f377e079da89